# Polynomial regression with one non-linear and other linear independent variables

Tags: statistics, regression, non-linear-regression

In a hypothetical situation where I have 3 independent variables and one of those variables has a non-linear relationship(exponential) with the dependent variable and the other two independent variables are linearly related to the dependent variable. In such a case, what would be the best approach for running a regression analysis?
Considering I tried transforming the one non-linear independent variable.

Comment: You mean something like `Y = a + b*X1 + c*X2 + d*exp(X3)`? That would be a *linear* regression since the variables are the parameters which enter linearly.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Although my confusion was, for an exponential relationship, polynomial regression is a good approach since it fits the parabolic nature of the relationship curve between dependent and independent variable. Would running a multiple linear regression still be a good idea?

Comment: Please write down your regression equation so that I and others can understand what you are asking.